# Yii: Get last inserted ID of related table in controller action during create

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a transaction where I am inserting a new record into TableB and depending if there is not the proper supporting record in TableA I will also be inserting into TableA and using that Primary Key as a Foreign key entry into TableB.

[image]

```
$transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
try 
{
    $tableA->IsActive = 'Y'; 
    $tableA->save();

    $model->TableAId = $tableA->TableAId;  //not sure what to put here for $tableA->TableAId
    $model->save();

    $transaction->commit(); 
}
```

In this situation can I use `Yii::app()->db->getLastInsertId();` for `$tableA->TableAId;`

Obviously accuracy is highly important here so I need to guarantee that the proper records align between TableA and TableB

Comment: what are the properties of tableAId column in db (for TableA)?

Comment: @bool.dev properties? auto-increment int

Comment: since it is auto-increment, it'll work with the code u already have, but make sure `if there is not the proper supporting record in TableA` check is properly handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, Your comment looks perfect.                                                $model->TableAId = $tableA->TableAId; // This is perfect!!
But code not. Following should be your code.

```
$transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
try 
{
    $tableA = TableA::model()->findByPk("id"); OR $tableA = new TableA;
    $tableA->IsActive = 'Y'; 
    $tableA->save();

    $model = new TableB;
    $model->TableAId = $tableA->TableAId;  //not sure what to put here for $tableA->TableAId // This is perfect!!
    $model->save();

    $transaction->commit(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I am missing something but if TableAId is an auto-incremented value in the database will this still work without querying the db first?

Comment: If you are saving using "new TableA" because it creates model object once you call save(); and you can use properties of that model.

Comment: Yes I am using new TableA that is part of my controller code, just didn't include that all here.  Working right now on building the rest of this out and the form to test it.

Comment: Then it's ok. there is no uncertainty